# Решение для дизайна карточки товара

Tags: html, css

Столкнулись с вопросом, как сделать так, чтобы все карточки товаров (еды, в нашем случае) стояли ровно относительно к друг другу.

Вот скриншот с сайта, как сейчас выглядят карточки:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

-- Из за количества символов в названии и в описании товара, карточки стоят не ровно.
Вот вопрос, как лучше и красиво можно реализовать, чтобы карточки стояли ровно относительно к друг другу? предложите, пожалуйста, свои идеи.

Comment: Есть мнение, что это вопрос не совсем в тему. А точнее совсем не в тему. Если бы вопрос был как реализовать идею, другое дело. А делегировать свой труд в большие массы - не соответствует тематике сайта. [help]

Comment: @SLy_huh  я способен реализовать идею любой сложности в области html&css, вот только вопрос в том, какие идеи и решения находили другие специалисты в практике.

Comment: фиксированная высота - решит проблему

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, так: обрезаем ту область с контентом, которая везде различного размера, а при наведении на карточку товара увеличиваем её; также нам понадобится абсолютно позиционированная обертка внутри карточки товара, чтобы при увеличении внутренностей не распадалась сетка.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.product {
  width: 190px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: -1px;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}

.product__inner {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding: 19px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.product__inner:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .3s;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.product__image {
  text-align: center;
}

.product__name {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: .3em 0 .5em;
}

.product__content {
  max-height: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height .3s;
}

.product:hover {
  z-index: 1;
}

.product:hover .product__content {
  max-height: 100px;
}

.product:hover .product__inner:before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

<div class="product">
  <div class="product__inner">
    <div class="product__image">
      <img src="http://pipsum.com/150x100.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="product__name">ololo product</div>
    <div class="product__content">ololo content, trololo content, really big content for serious guys</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="product">
  <div class="product__inner">
    <div class="product__image">
      <img src="http://pipsum.com/150x100.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="product__name">ololo product</div>
    <div class="product__content">ololo content</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="product">
  <div class="product__inner">
    <div class="product__image">
      <img src="http://pipsum.com/150x100.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="product__name">ololo product</div>
    <div class="product__content">ololo content, trololo content</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="product">
  <div class="product__inner">
    <div class="product__image">
      <img src="http://pipsum.com/150x100.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="product__name">ololo product</div>
    <div class="product__content">really medium content for girls</div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Почему бы не задать максимальную высоту блокам?

Comment: Собственно, как вы себе это представляете? если количество символов отличаются.

Comment: Вот так ![](http://www.pixic.ru/i/R0V153f3X1F8C4G3.jpg)

Comment: Еще для примера можете глянуть другие сайты схожей тематики. Должен быть задан фиксированный размер блока (т.е. исходя из размера блока с максимальным кол-вом символов).

Comment: Конечно до такого варианта догадаться не трудно. Но пустые части в карточке не красиво смотрятся.